# Rails way of sensibly displaying HTTP status codes across entire application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-codes, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan

Is there a simple way of telling an entire rails app to display a boilerplate HTTP status code page/view when one is generated, preferably without editing each and every controller?

For example, when trying to access a part of the app a user is unauthorized to access, instead of seeing this locally:

[image]

or this on heroku:

[image]

It would be more user friendly to see something generic but informative like

[image]

Is it possible to make the entire app show informative HTTP status code messages in the event of anything other than a 200?

Comment: This might give you some ideas https://anoobbava.github.io/blog/2018/03/22/create-custom-error-pages-in-rails/